# How to use inlcude and content block in HTML code

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I have a question for you. I have the following structure:

```
__Base.html
__main_sidebar.html
__conto_economico.html
```

The _main_sidebar.html is the following:

```
{% block nav_links_ul %}
        <nav class="mt-2">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu" data-accordion="false">
            {% block nav_links_outer %}
            <li class="nav-header">{% block nav_heading %}PERFORMANCE MONITORING{% endblock %}</li>

            {% block nav_links %}

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                        <i class="nav-icon fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
                        <p>Dashboard</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="/conto_economico" class="nav-link">
                            <i class="nav-icon fas fa-chart-bar"></i>
                            <p>Conto Economico</p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
```

It is include in my base.html:

```
{% block nav_sidebar %}
   {% include 'adminlte/lib/_main_sidebar.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

My conto_economico.html is an extends of base.html

```
{% extends 'adminlte/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Now I want that, when I press on the link in my sidebar (ad example /conto_economico) and the new page is upload, I want tha the relative nav-link become **`nav-link active`**  as the following:

```
<a href="/conto_economico" class="nav-link active">
```

Could I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may include your template with some context passed to it like

```
{% include 'adminlte/lib/_main_sidebar.html' with active_menu_item=active_menu_item %}
```

and then in your view when sending data to this template (or with a middleware) send a context key and value like:

```py
context = {'active_menu_item': 'conto_economico', ...}
```

and then in your template check it out like:

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a href="/conto_economico"
       class="nav-link {% if active_menu_item=='conto_economico' %} active {% endif %}">
        <i class="nav-icon fas fa-chart-bar"></i>
        <p>Conto Economico</p>
    </a>
</li>
```

also note that you may need to change your extended view too.
let me know if that worked for you.

- [django include tempate tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried your suggestions but django give me the following error: `django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '=='conto_economico'' from 'active_menu_item=='conto_economico''`

Comment: I have added the `{% include 'adminlte/lib/_main_sidebar.html' with active_menu_item=active_menu_item %}` in my conto_economico.html, the context in the view of conto_economico and `class="nav-link {% if active_menu_item=='conto_economico' %} active {% endif %}">` inside the main_sidebar.html

Comment: @FedericoDeMarco sorry i was away, great to hear that! ur wlc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use as many blocks as you want. just name them unique.
two blocks cannot have the same name.

Base Template---

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'cpanel/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'cpanel/css/main.css' %}">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'cpanel/css/font_awesome_css_all.css' %}"/>
         <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
         <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

     <title>Document</title>

    {% block head %}

    {% endblock head %}


    </head>

<body>

    {% block heading %}

        block for heading

    {% endblock heading %}

    {% block content %}
        block for content
    {% endblock content %}
</body>

{% block script %}
        block for script
{% endblock script %}

</html>
```

Child template---

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block head %}

{% endblock head %}


{% block heading %}
    <ol class="breadcrumb mb-4">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Dashboard/Vendors</li>
    </ol>
    <hr>
{% endblock heading %}

{% block content %}

{% endblock content %}
```